My React Native app doesn't start anymore when I run: npm run android
my app was running perfectly before I tried to compile it for production by running npx expo run:android --variant release which returned with an error.
Now, when I run npm run android I get this error:
>  C:/Users/Mobile Apps/React Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/1g6k43ua/x86_64/CMakeFiles/expo-modules-core.dir/./
    

has 196 characters.  The maximum full path to an object file is 250
    characters (see CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX).  Object file

      C_/Users/Mobile_Apps/React_Native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/expo-modules-core/common/cpp/ObjectDeallocator.cpp.o

    cannot be safely placed under this directory.  The build may not work
    correctly.


  ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s
384 actionable tasks: 19 executed, 365 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\Mobile Apps\React Native\AwesomeProject\android\gradlew.bat app:assembleDebug -x lint -x test --configure-on-demand --build-cache 
-PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64 exited with non-zero code: 1

There's my package.json:
 
I tried to cd android then run --stacktrace and --scan in order to get more insights and it gave me info about packages that was deprecated. I deleted them, now I get these  results:  

Please never share screenshots of text anywhere, unless you want to show more than the text like colors or IDE annotations. Instead share the pure text with proper markup. Scrennshots of text are hard to read - especially on mobile -, very hard to copy, and nearly impossible to search for.

The --stacktrace and --scan calls you made are practically useless, as you need to add those to the call that actually fails, which is not what you did. Also when using --scan, the important part is the build scan URL printed in the end of the output. Also, if you just scroll up where you made the first screenshot, chances are that the actual problem is already logged above what you screenshotted.

@Vampire I just edited it. Please tell me if you see where the problem might be

Also, the build scan display 0 failures

Again, the build scan displays 0 failures because you did not run the failing build, but some other build, that is not helpful as I already said. And now that you added some more of the error message, what is unclear? The message is quite clear, isn't it?

Try moving your app into a different folder
For example
From
C:\Users\Mobile Apps\React Native\AwesomeProject\android\
Move it to
C:\ReactNative\Android
It could be the windows problem, and there were simmiliar cases where moving to shorter directory helped
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1941
ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22444

Thanks for your help, I moved the project into a shorter directory and it works.

Hi @TetSigma, would you be interested in a collab ? If yes please contact me at: ilagouandrew@gmail.com
